# PHP Why is only one array returned in multidimensional array after a foreach

Tags: database, oop, for-loop, foreach, php-7.2

So im trying to make a multidimensional array, inserting dates under their day. However the days only show one of their dates coming from the database. It also looks like its repeating itself. Eventually my goal is to get all dates under their respected day.

What I tried:
-array_push, trying to push the new data in the array.
-A for loop

The code for handling

```
$currentDate = new Date();

        $month = $currentDate->getCurrentDate()->format("m");
        $year = $currentDate->getCurrentDate()->format("Y");

        $availableCollection = new AvailabilitiesCollection();


        try {
            $availableCollection->add(Availability::getByMonthAndYear($this->db, $month, $year));
            $availabilities = $availableCollection->get();
            foreach ($availabilities as $this->availability ){
                $this->date = new \DateTime($this->availability['date']);
                $this->dayLabel = $this->date->format('D');
                $this->dataDb[] = $this->dayLabel;
            }

            $count = array_count_values($this->dataDb);


            foreach ($availabilities as $this->availability) {
                $this->date = new \DateTime($this->availability['date']);
                $this->dayLabel = $this->date->format('D');

                $this->insertAvailabilityInDays[$this->dayLabel] = array();

                $availableData = array(
                        'id' => $this->availability['reservation_id'],
                        'date' => $this->availability['date'],
                        'start_at' => $this->availability['start_at'],
                        'end_at' => $this->availability['end_at']
                    );

                array_push($this->insertAvailabilityInDays[$this->dayLabel], $availableData);

//                for($i = 0; $i < $count[$this->dayLabel]; $i++){
//                    $availableData = array(
//                        'id' => $this->availability['reservation_id'],
//                        'date' => $this->availability['date'],
//                        'start_at' => $this->availability['start_at'],
//                        'end_at' => $this->availability['end_at']
//                    );
//
//                    array_push($this->insertAvailabilityInDays[$this->dayLabel], $availableData);
//                }

                var_dump($this->insertAvailabilityInDays);
                continue;




            }


//            var_dump($this->insertAvailabilityInDays);
//            exit;


        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e);
        }
```

The data in my db:

```
+----------------+------------+----------+--------+
| reservation_id |    date    | start_at | end_at |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------+
|              6 | 2020-01-22 |  12:30   | 12:45  |
|              7 | 2020-01-20 |  12:50   | 13:00  |
|              8 | 2020-01-22 |  15:45   | 16:00  |
|              9 | 2020-01-21 |  14:45   | 15:00  |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------+
```

My current output:

```
array (size=1)
  'Wed' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2020-01-22' (length=10)
      'start_at' => string '12:30:00' (length=8)
      'end_at' => string '12:45:00' (length=8)
/var/source/app/classes/System/Handlers/CalendarHandler.php:87:
array (size=2)
  'Wed' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2020-01-22' (length=10)
      'start_at' => string '12:30:00' (length=8)
      'end_at' => string '12:45:00' (length=8)
  'Mon' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2020-01-20' (length=10)
      'start_at' => string '12:50:00' (length=8)
      'end_at' => string '13:00:00' (length=8)
/var/source/app/classes/System/Handlers/CalendarHandler.php:87:
array (size=2)
  'Wed' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2020-01-22' (length=10)
      'start_at' => string '15:45:00' (length=8)
      'end_at' => string '16:00:00' (length=8)
  'Mon' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2020-01-20' (length=10)
      'start_at' => string '12:50:00' (length=8)
      'end_at' => string '13:00:00' (length=8)
/var/source/app/classes/System/Handlers/CalendarHandler.php:87:
array (size=3)
  'Wed' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2020-01-22' (length=10)
      'start_at' => string '15:45:00' (length=8)
      'end_at' => string '16:00:00' (length=8)
  'Mon' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2020-01-20' (length=10)
      'start_at' => string '12:50:00' (length=8)
      'end_at' => string '13:00:00' (length=8)
  'Tue' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '9' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2020-01-21' (length=10)
      'start_at' => string '14:45:00' (length=8)
      'end_at' => string '15:00:00' (length=8)
```

I`m expecting that every date goes in the array with their day. Together with its database information.

E.g:

```
'Wed' => 
    array (size=4)
    0 =>
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2020-01-22' (length=10)
      'start_at' => string '12:30:00' (length=8)
      'end_at' => string '16:45:00' (length=8)
    1 =>
      'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2020-01-22' (length=10)
      'start_at' => string '15:45:00' (length=8)
      'end_at' => string '16:00:00' (length=8)
```

Comment: Not sure if this correct your code is difficult to decipher. Seem you have a lot of props that could confuse things. Try: $this->insertAvailabilityInDays[$this->dayLabel][] = $availableData

Comment: @TomShaw I was about to reply that I already tried this, but then it actually worked. I dont know why it did now. Im sorry if I explained it poorly, what is exactly difficult so I can change it?

Comment: I tend to avoid properties and utilize function params unless it absolutely necessary. I've already gotten into an argument with a co worker about this, sure you can create tons of props but it's more about simplifying things and readability.

Comment: Absolutely, I mean thats what we all should do. I am a student and still learning alot. Can you tell me what you would avoid or change, so I can apply that the next time.

Comment: My advice is to keep it simple, the code formatted and the variable names well thought out. The reason being is code bases grow in complexity. I have one client and now after 10 years you should see his code base. Other than that I'm super happy it's working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Like @TomShaw mentioned, indeed changing `$this->insertAvailabilityInDays[$this->dayLabel][] = $availableData` fixed the problem.